# Preserve newlines in pre-populated textarea in Rails using form helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textarea, newline

Assume you have this:

```
<%= form_for post, remote: true do |f| %>
  <!-- some other fields -->

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I easily solve the problem while displaying `content` using `post.content.gsub(/\n/, "<br />")`, but while I am editing the post's `content`, the `textarea` completely ignores the newlines (since there is no way to run `gsub` on `f.text_area :content`).

Due to this, long texts with several paragraphs completely lose their newlines.

I found many such questions like this, but never specifically for this scenario.

Comment: try `f.text_area :content, value: do_your_gsub`

Comment: ah, I hadn't thought of that.

However, when I use `post.content.gsub(/\n/, "<br />")`, it just shows the literal string `<br />` at the newlines rather than putting in a line break.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the solution was quite simple. Thanks to apneadiving for bringing to my attention the fact that I can simply add `value: post.content` to manually populate the content of the post to the textarea field, which allows me to manipulate it.

This solved my problem:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, value: post.content.gsub(/\n/, '\n') %>
```

Comment: I changed the `post.content.gsub(/\n/, '\n')` to `(post.content || "").gsub(/\n/, '\n')` because I was getting an error when using the form for a new post (where the content is blank/nil).